# .NET 5: It is possible to create a link to the Registration Razor Page inside a .cshtml file of an MVC application? Please read explanation

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-5

So I have this .NET 5 MVC application. However it is using Microsoft Identity. When I scaffold Identity pages, they are razor pages, which works fine anyway.

However I need to remove the link of the registration page from the login form to inside the application. I said, uh, that's easy, I just link to the razor page inside my custom user view. However I can't find a way to do this.

I have tried various code around this line:

```
<a asp-page="/Identity/Account/Register">Register a New User</a>
```

That "/Identity/Account/Register" path is not my invention. Is the url that I see in the browser after localhost when testing to click the register link inside login page.

I tried giving the full folder path, but it didn't work either :(

This is my Identity file structure:

[image: Identity File Structure]

And the .cshtml from where I'm trying to link the register page, is this index file inside the users folder:

[image: cshtml file]

How do I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The LoginUrl is specified in the [CookieOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633896/asp-net-core-identity-change-login-url). You can then inject the `IOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>` wherever you want and use this `LoginUrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **asp-area** tag helper in your anchor tag.

```
<a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register a New User</a>
```

You can also try

```
<a asp-page="/Account/Register">Register a New User</a>
```

I've answered a similar query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55398331/4483395).

Comment: First line worked flawlessly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know that I could help you. :)